# Sequence convergent proof $\left\{ \frac{1 + \cos(2n)}{15 + \sqrt{n} } \right\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

$\left\{ \frac{1 + \cos(2n)}{15 + \sqrt{n}}\right\}$

I know that this converges to zero.

My attempt:

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N > 0$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > N$, then $\left|\frac{1 + \cos(2n)}{15 + \sqrt{n}}  \right| < \epsilon$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary

Choose $N = \frac{4}{\epsilon^2} > 0$

Suppose $n > N$, then $\left|\frac{1 + \cos(2n)}{15 + \sqrt{n}}\right| \leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}} < \frac{2}{\sqrt{N}} = \epsilon$

Therefore it converges by definition of convergent sequence

Is this right?

Comment: No, because $4/\epsilon^2$ is not necessarily an integer (but you can easily fix this by choosing $N>4/\epsilon^2$)

Comment: Except what @CarlosIsraelJrl has suggested, everything else appears to be correct!

Comment: @Tinler I think your proof is right.

Comment: @CarlosIsraelJrl or  he can chose it to be $[4/\epsilon^2]$

Comment: @Mohamez If by $[]$ you mean the ceiling function, then yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** it is worth mentioning [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) too $$-1\leq \cos(2n)\leq 1 \Rightarrow 0\leq \left|\frac{1+\cos(2n)}{15+\sqrt{n}}\right| < \frac{2}{15+\sqrt{n}}$$